# How can I parse/print p2pstate.bin outside of the daemon?

Tags: daemon, peer

Essentially I am looking for some method, e.g. using Python, that I can get results equivalent to the `print_pl` command that is run inside the daemon.

I.e. I don't want to have to run the daemon to see the contents of `p2pstate.bin` in human readable form.

Any ideas on how to read the data in the file? I am not sure the formatting of this binary file to decode.

The reason is, I am interested in reading/parsing many different p2pstate.bin files in an automated way. Specifically I want the IP address and last_seen fields from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure the formatting of this binary file to decode.

This uses the Boost serialization [library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) (more specifically `boost::archive::portable_binary_[io]archive`), and so the easiest solution would be to use C++, Boost and include the relevant files from the Monero project (e.g. [src/p2p/net_peerlist.cpp](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/f49fc9b4876382d5c6f08fd7a6125b554c49e260/src/p2p/net_peerlist.cpp)).

Trying to parse this in Python is non-trivial.